# On hover display an other element - css

Tags: css

I am using sass, can be the problem that the ~ symbol is not working in scss file?

```
.category-inner:hover~.subcategories {
  display: block;
}

.subcategories {
  display: none;
}

<div class="category-inner"></div>
...
<div class="subcategories"></div>
```

Comment: Make sure you use real quotes, either `'` or `"` in your real code and not "smart" or "curly" quotes like you have in your example `”`

Comment: What is the output of your css? Is it the same as scss?

Comment: I've created a fiddle where this works, and there is nothing that should prevent it from working: https://jsfiddle.net/_ajm/3d7qcho1/1/. If you check the output of your SCSS build, what does it look like? Are the right selectors in place?